# Put/Take ; In/Out: What is a verb useable for both?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

"He was asked to put the blocks in and take the blocks out of the box."
What is an alternative to "put/take" in this sentence, so that the sentence can read "He was asked to [verb] the blocks in and out of the box."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *to move* would work?

> He was asked to move the blocks in and out of the box.

It feels natural for concrete objects like blocks, but less so for liquids. In that case, 'put' and 'take' don't sound natural either; I'd choose something like *to pour*.

Comment: Would that also work for mass nouns, like water, butter, or rice?

Answer (score 1):

A good general word is [**transfer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfer).

> He was asked to *transfer* the blocks in and out of the box.

It has the added benefit of sounding natural with almost any item I can think of—not just blocks. It even works with abstract nouns, as in *I transferred from one course to another.*